# Software center asks me to repair, but cannot because: "installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmtp-dev"

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, software-center

The software center asked me to repair, but I encountered the following error. How can I resolve this error?

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmtp-dev:
 libmtp-dev depends on libmtp8 (= 1.0.2-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libmtp8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libmtp-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmtp-dev
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmtp-dev:
 libmtp-dev depends on libmtp8 (= 1.0.2-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libmtp8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libmtp-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this problem, just on my opinion is to go through steps.
1.Close the Ubuntu Software store properly.
2.Disk Analyze
3.Terminal, "sudo apt-get update"
4. Restart the machine properly.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should fix your problem.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```